# High numbers in SVG makes the element disappear

Tags: svg

If I put a big number as a coordinate into SVG elements, these elements doesn't show up.

```css
.line {
  stroke-dasharray: 10, 5;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FF6600;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <svg height="500" width="800">
        <polyline class="line" points="0,300 16000000,300"></polyline>
    </svg>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JojbKQ

If you change the 16,000,000 coordinate in the polyline to something smaller (15M) it shows up. I see this problem mainly in Chrome, but it appears also in another browsers too but in some of them (Firefox) for much higher numbers. It even crashes browser with high-enough numbers(Firefox).

When I remove the stroke-dasharray attribute from the element, i get this problem at like 3 orders of magnitude higher numbers.

You may ask why I need such a big numbers there. I have a zoomable scene and even reasonable coordinates reaches this limit pretty easily once you zoom in deep enough.

Does anyone know about any kind of workaround? Thanks

Comment: You should report the crash to the FF developers. Malformed input in html/svg/whatever should NOT be able to take down the browser.

Comment: I'll double check the behavior and try to report it. Thanks for the suggestion.